# Can't get codemirror instance in content script of Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, codemirror

I am trying to get CodeMirror instance on the website then get the code inside in this Chrome extension.

My code works fine in Console.

[image]

However it does not work when I use these code in content script of my Chrome extension.

Here is my content script code:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (request.name == "GetChosenCodeMirrorText"){
     console.log("content script starts");
     var codeMirrorElementArray = document.getElementsByClassName("cm-s-default");
     
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(codeMirrorElementArray, function(codeMirrorElement){
            console.log(codeMirrorElement);
            var codeMirrorEditor = codeMirrorElement.CodeMirror;
            var line = codeMirrorEditor.getLine(1);
            console.log(line);
        });
     
     sendResponse({codeMirrorElementArray: "Just Testing"});
    }
  });
```

Here is my manifest.json

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "xxx",
    "description": "xxx",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    //always need an injection
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            //"matches": ["://*/*"],
            "css": ["codemirror.css"],
            //"js": ["codemirror.js", "underscore.js", "content_script.js"],
            "js": ["codemirror.js", "content_script.js"],
            //"js": ["content_script.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "permissions" : ["tabs"],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

[image]

And when I run this code, here is what I get from console:

Or is there a better way to get CodeMirror instance on a website?

Comment: You need to [insert that code into page context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script).

Comment: Thanks! It helps!